# How to tune for multilabel classififcation?

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

I am trying to develop a model for a multi-label classification problem. My training dataset has ~550k observations, 2.7k inputs and 84 labels (already one hot encoded) for outputs.

I have gone through the following materials:
http://scikit.ml/index.html
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/introduction-to-multi-label-classification/
https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff
which goes through similar ways to tackle the problem. 
aI was initially considering using BinaryRelevance with XGBClassifier or MLPClassifier. I havea tried running  few variations of the following code:

```
clf_mlp = MultiOutputClassifier(
        MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(2000,),
                     activation='relu', 
                    max_iter=10000, 
                    verbose=False, 
                    early_stopping=False
                     )).fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions_mlp = clf_mlp.predict(X_test)
accuracy_mlp=accuracy_score(y_test,predictions_mlp)
```

However my accuracy is only at 8%... any tips on either tuning or other algorithsm which may work better?